# In scipy.optimize.minimize, how can I feed optional arguments into the args=() tuple?

Tags: python, parameter-passing, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

So I have some funciton

```
def fun(x,y=None):
    # Do some stuff
```

and I want to minimize this function over x, but *sometimes* I will want to have an additional argument y. (Essentially, I want y to always take its default value, except when I'm minimizing.)

Usually, if the function was just `def fun(x,y):` I'd be able to do `scipy.optimize.minimize(x,args=(y))`. But what do I do when y is an optional variable? putting `args=(y=value)` is giving me invalid syntax, (and, sure, it looks very wrong), but I'm not sure what the correct syntax would be.

I'm using Python 3.7 if that's relevant.

Comment: This really sounds like you should have two functions. (It's straightforward to solve the `minimize` problem - you use the exact same call you would use if `y` wasn't optional, since optional arguments can still be passed positionally - but the description of how you want to use this function really doesn't sound like a job for 1 function.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `minimize` only takes optional arguments without keywords for the function it calls. This is written in [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html), since it describes the function to be called as `fun(x, *args)`, without any optional arguments.

If your function is `f(x, y=None, z=None)` you would have to call `scipy.optimize.minimize(f, x, (y, z))`.

Instead I would construct a lambda that passes the arguments as keywords directly. Thus doing:

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(lambda x: f(x, z=0), x)
```

which makes it clear which optional arguments you are passing.